# Intel compiler in visual studio not finding boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, intel-composer

I am trying to install mlpack in vs2013. msvc2013 is not compatible, so I am using Intel C++ compiler XE 14.0. However, Intel compiler is not finding the boost libraries.

Using only MSVC -

```
C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\build> cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" ....
-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:PATH="C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\packages\boost.1.63.0.0\lib\native\include" 
-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR:PATH="C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\packages\boost_libs" ..
```

Output -

```
....
Found the following Boost libraries:
  program_options
  unit_test_framework
  serialization
....
```

Using MSVC and Intel toolkit -

```
C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\build> cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" -T"Intel C++ compiler XE 14.0" ....
-DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR:PATH="C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\packages\boost.1.63.0.0\lib\native\include" 
-DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR:PATH="C:\projects\mlpack-2.1.1\packages\boost_libs" ..
```

Output -

```
Could not find the following Boost libraries:
      boost_program_options
      boost_unit_test_framework
      boost_serialization
```

Why is the intel unable to find? I installed the boost libraries using NuGet package manager. Should I use some other boost libs for intel compiler?

Comment: I see the same `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` path in both cases. Does this directory contain both sets of binaries? The libraries are identified by a toolset tag, and CMake searches for a [different tag depending on the compiler](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Boost NuGet packages do not have binaries for Intel compiler. Boost NuGet package contains binaries from the [Prebuilt windows binaries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/) only. In the future, I'm happy to add new binaries as soon as they are available to download from some trusted resource.